# CodeIgniter Fatal error: Class on CORE controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created under application/core folder a file called Auth_controller.php.
I am using CodeIgniter 3.
php 5.3.3
Centos 6.9

The content is

```
class Auth_Controller extends CI_Controller{
```

in config file i declare

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Auth_';
```

Then finally when i called it...

```
class Home extends Auth_Controller {
```

it gives me a

```
Fatal error: Class 'Auth_Controller' not found in /var/www/html/calllist/application/controllers/Home.php on line 3

Message:  Class 'Auth_Controller' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Auth_';` settings means you want to extend core CI classes.

If you want to extend `CI_Controller` then you class name should be `Auth_Controller` if you want to extend model your class name should be `'Auth_Model'`

**But Remember those classes/files should be inside your `application\core` folder**

For more details please look at [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Auth_Controller like below mentioned code.

```
<?php

require_once("secure_area.php");

class Reports extends Secure_area {
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of `Auth_Controller` must be in `application\core` directory. Otherwise you need to manually include class to your controller file.